# How to use cloud code on parse server deployed on heroku?

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm wondering how I can implement cloud code on a parse server I have deployed on heroku and MongoDB (the app is not connected to parse). I know there is a Command Line install tool to deploy cloud code with heroku, but doing that I have to create a new parse and heroku app instead of just adding it to the parse server I have deployed. How can I add this functions

Comment: Push the modified cloud/main.js to your Git repo ?

Comment: Then will it all function properly when I call the function in my app using the parse SDK?

Comment: It should, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue here is the way to put the latest code from 'cloud/main.js' to heroku from terminal

```
 $ git add ./cloud/main.js
 $ git commit -m "Changed configuration values"
 $ git push heroku master
```

Now call your newly uploaded function from the app they will now work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an  `hello` test function in cloud/main.js:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hi');
});
```

If you can successfully call it from your code, you're good to go. Just pushing your own functions to the Git repo should work. If you use the Github-Heroku integration and you've enabled [automatic deploys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys), you don't have anything more to do, else do a manual deploy.

Comment: How do I push my own functions to the Git Reo I'm using?

Comment: @user6099709 Add them to the `main.js` file

Comment: I'm having an issue. I'm updating the cloud/main.js file on GitHub, but none of the new functions are recognized. It will only recognize the 'hello' function in the answer.

Comment: @user6099709 So you're updating the code in your Github, but the new code is not automatically deployed on the Heroku server, is that it ?

Comment: But I'm not sure if it's deploying***

Comment: @user6099709 see updated answer for Github => Heroku deploys.

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated